# Is using user agent string to detect IE11 nowadays no longer problematic?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am aware of the inadequacies and cons of using the user agent string in detecting the browser but in my current project at the company, the only thing that is problematic in running the site is Internet Explorer 11 because of its inability to read Javascript Classes we made which is very long and the arrows of ES6 we use. As with what others have tried to do, I put this code into my controller and run php on blade. This only applies to 4 pages of the whole website. I am aware that feature detection is most certainly recommended but if I'm using UA sniffing solely for making a few pages work in only IE11 alone, and since IE11 is basically left for dead by MS and no new IE versions/features will be coming which means the string 'trident/' won't change, is this a viable option? If possible, I would like some opinions.

Controller

```
$exactBrowserNameUA = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(strpos(strtolower($exactBrowserNameUA), 'trident/')) {
   Session::put('is_internet_explorer', true);
} else {
   Session::put('is_internet_explorer', false);
}
```

Blade

```
@if(Session::get('is_internet_explorer') === false)
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/original_es6_code.js')}}" charset="UTF-8"></script>
@else
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/babel_transpiled_code.js')}}" charset="UTF-8"></script>
@endif
```

Comment: If it's just `class`es and arrow functions, consider using Babel instead to transpile automatically

Comment: I used Babel but offline transpile. If isn't IE11, include the original written code but if it is, the Babel-transpiled code is included instead. I noticed the transpiled code is really slow, sometimes taking 10-13 seconds for the page to show up and finish loading.